# Problem with const char* in C

Tags: c, casting

I am basically trying to get the time with

```
struct timeval tv = { };
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
```

And it works. The problem is that the function that is going to accept as an argument the time is of type const char*

So i did

```
const char *time;
time = &tv.tv_sec;
```

The problem is, that tv.tv_sec is of type time_t and i need to plug it in

```
const char *time
```

to pass it on to the function that needs const char*

How do i do it? Placing an integer into a const char* 
I've tried some simple ways of casting it, however i am not that experienced with C

Comment: You mean that you want to convert that `time_t` into a string, then send the string to a function that accepts a string as argument?

Comment: You will have to convert the seconds (which are an integer) into a string, and pass that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format an integer as a string you should use `snprintf`.

For example:

```
char resultString[64];

snprintf(resultString, sizeof(resultString), "Current time : %d", tv.tv_sec);
```

Comment: Yeah, i get 

db-mysql.c:144:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘snprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:62:1: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char’
db-mysql.c:144:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘__time_t’
db-mysql.c:144:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘__time_t’

Comment: This is it basically

**const char timee;
    const char *timer;
`
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

    snprintf(timee, sizeof(timee), "%d", tv.tv_sec);

    timer = &timee;**

Answer (score 5):

When you find yourself needing to cast a time pointer into a char pointer, that is a hint that there is something very wrong. You should take a second look at the problem.

You don't describe the other function that is accepting a const char*, or I would have a better idea of what is happening.

I suspect that you may be required to convert the time integers into a character string and pass a pointer to the beginning of that string. To do that you might want to use a function called strftime.

Answer (score 1):

Directly useable C functions are:

- [`ctime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/ctime/) (input is of type `time_t`)
- [`asctime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/asctime/) (input is of type `struct tm`)

If you need control over format use:

- [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) (input is of type `struct tm`)

The linked pages contain examples of use. The string has to be preallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Check `sprintf` or `snprintf`.